# Hide resources (rows) without any events in FullCalendar Scheduler

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

Is there any way to hide the resources (rows) in a One Day view of a FullCalendar Scheduler instance if there are no events associated with that resource(s) (row) on the selected day?

If I, then, go and change the date and the hidden resource has an event associated with it, I'd like to re-display that resource together with its event(s).

The use case for this is an app that allows entering expressions of interest of viewing for multiple venues for multiple people. In a one day view, my resources are the venues. I don't want to display a venue unless it has one booking.

Comment: ticket that captures what you are asking for https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/98

Answer (score 5):

Use `filterResourcesWithEvents: true`

Reference Link: [FilterResources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/filterResourcesWithEvents)